# Hudson and configurations (debug, release, parallel, etc)

Tags: debugging, configuration, parameters, hudson, release

I wonder if there are some good practices for testing multiple configurations in Hudson. We compile tests in debug and release mode and also toggle MPI on and off.

The make system takes a series of parameters (DEBUG=FALSE, OPT=TRUE, MPI=TRUE) and does the right thing, producing test executables that are well labeled. I could probably create a monolithic control script that does everything, but I wonder if I am missing some facility for iterating through a list of parameters. Even better would be if I could clean the project in between.

Anyone have an opinion? Is this best done with separate projects? With parameters? Just by writing a very complete script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the option **Build multi-configuration project** when you first create your job.

In the multi-configuration build, you can add an "Axis" that defines a set of values for one of your build parameters. Then the build script can reference the Axis parameter as an environment variable. Define multiple axes and Hudson will run through all of the combinations.