# Jenkins - Running instances of single build concurrently

Tags: jenkins

I'd like to be able to run several builds of the same Jenkins job simultaneously.

Example:

1. Build [*jenkins_job_1*]: calls an ant script with parameter 'A'
2. Build [*jenkins_job_1*]: calls an ant script with parameter 'B'
3. repeat as necessary
4. each instance of the job runs simultaneously, rather than through a queue.

The reason I'd like to do this is to avoid having to create several jobs that are nearly identical, all of which would need to be maintained.

Is there a way to do this, or maybe another solution (ie — dynamically create a job from a base job and remove it after it's finished)?

Answer (score 38):

Jenkins has a check box: "Execute concurrent builds if necessary"

If you check this, then it'll start multiple builds for a job.

This works with the "This build is parameterized" checkbox.

You would still trigger the builds, passing your `A` or `B` as parameters.  You can use another job to trigger them or you could do it manually via a script.

Comment: In version 2.204.2, _untick_ the checkbox labelled "Do not allow concurrent builds"

Comment: I love it when they change the names of things.

Answer (score 10):

You can select **Build a Multi-configuration project** (Matrix build) when you create the job. Then, under the job's configuration, you can define the **Configuration Matrix** which lets you specify one or more parameters (axes) for different builds. Regarding running simultaneously, you should be able to run as many simultaneous builds as you have executors (with the appropriate label).

Unfortunately, the [Jenkins wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project) lacks documentation about this setup. There are a couple previous SO questions, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424295/experience-with-hudson-building-matrix-project) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210678/hudson-and-configurations-debug-release-parallel-etc), that might provide a little guidance. There was a "recent" [blog post](http://jenkins-ci.org/content/recent-label-and-matrix-project-improvement) about setting up a multi-configuration job to perform builds on various platforms.

Comment: The blog post mentioned above is helpful

Answer (score 4):

A newer (and better) solution is the [Jenkins Job DSL Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin).

We've been using it with great success.  Our job configurations are now disposable... we can set up a huge stack of complicated jobs from some groovy files and a couple template jobs.  It's great.

I'm liking it a lot more than the matrix builds, which were complicated and harder to understand.

Comment: Could you state how to achieve the "Execute concurrent builds if necessary" in Job DSL?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing stopping you doing this using the [Jenkins pipeline DSL](https://jenkins.io/solutions/pipeline/).

We have the same pipeline running in parallel in order to model combined loads for an application that exposes web services, provides a database to several external applications, receives data via several work queues and has a GUI front end. The business gives us non-functional requirements (NFRs) which our application must meet that guarantees its responsiveness even at busy times.

The different instances of the pipeline are run with different parameters. The first instance might be `WS_Load`, the second `GUI_Load` and the third `Daily_Update_Load`, modelling a large data queue that needs processing within a certain time-frame. More can be added depending on which combination of loads we're wanting to test.

Other answers have talked about the checkboxes for concurrent builds, but I wanted to mention another issue: resource contention.

If your pipeline uses temporary files or [stashes](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#stash-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build) files between pipeline stages, the instances can end up pulling the rug from under each others' feet. For example you can end up overwriting a file in one concurrent instance while another instance expects to find the pre-overwritten version of the same stash. We use the following code to ensure stashes and temporary filenames are unique per concurrent instance:

```
    def concurrentStash(stashName, String includes) {
        /* make a stash unique to this pipeline and build
           that can be unstashed using concurrentUnstash() */
        echo "Safe stashing $includes in ${concurrentSafeName(stashName)}..."
        stash name: concurrentSafeName(stashName), includes: includes
    }
  
    def concurrentSafeName(name) {
        /* make a name or name component unique to this pipeline and build
         * guards against contention caused by two or more builds from the same
         * Jenkinsfile trying to:
         *   - read/write/delete the same file
         *   - stash/unstash under the same name
         */
        "${name}-${BUILD_NUMBER}-${JOB_NAME}"
    }
  
    def concurrentUnstash(stashName) {
        echo "Safe unstashing ${concurrentSafeName(stashName)}..."
        unstash name: concurrentSafeName(stashName)
    }
```

We can then use `concurrentStash stashName` and `concurrentUnstash stashName` and the concurrent instances will have no conflict.

If, say, the two pipelines both need to store stats, we can do something like this for filenames:

```
def statsDir = concurrentSafeName('stats')
```

and then the instances will each use a unique filename to store their output.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a build and configure it with parameters.  Click the `This build is parameterized` checkbox and add your desired param(s) in the Configuration of the build.  You can then fire off simultaneous builds using different parameters.

Side note: The "Bulk Builder" in Jenkins might push it into a queue, but there's also a `This bulk build is parameterized` checkbox.

Comment: I tried this previously but I couldn't get them to run concurrently.
After going back, I noticed a "Execute concurrent builds if necessary" option which I didn't see before. It worked afterwards.

Comment: @qpi: It should work as you desired after checking "Execute concurrent builds if necessary" check box

Comment: will this create different work space for each running build of a job..or there will be only one workspace for the job . please let  me know how workspace will be managed in case of concurrent builds running simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a pretty large build queue and I performed below steps to run jobs in
parallel in jenkins to reduce number of jobs waiting in queue

1. For each job you need to navigate to configure and select the checkbox stating
   "Execute concurrent builds if necessary"
2. Navigate to Manage -> Configure System -> look for "# of executors" and set the no
   of parallel executors you want (in my case it was set to 0 and I updated it to 2)