# Jenkins not able to start concurrent builds for same job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am not able to start concurrent builds for same job in jenkins though I set number of executors as 4 for that node.

I have only one node N1 for which number of executors are set to 4. Now I created a job J1. When a  Build N1-J1-B1 is already running, I am not able to start another build N1-J1-B2. Build B2 is waiting in queue until B1 is done.

I believe Jenkins must support this feature, Am I missing any settings here?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/17789611/1213907 - set the execute concurrent builds if necessary box

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jenkins - Running instances of single build concurrently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153255/jenkins-running-instances-of-single-build-concurrently)

Comment: Thanks KeepCalmAndCarryOn and Peter Schuetze.

Answer (score 1):

To make @KeepCalmAndCarryOn's comment more obvious, you have to enable the `Execute concurrent builds if necessary` option on your job's configuration.

[image: make sure this is checked]