# how to config Jenkins job to make it can be executed on several nodes, but on one node, the job cannot be executed simultaneously

Tags: jenkins

For example, I click 'build now' button on Jenkins UI three times to trigger three builds (build1, build2, build3) for 'Job A' (or project A).

I hope the three builds can be executed on three nodes (for example, build1 on NodeA, build2 on NodeB and build3 on NodeC). That means the three builds can be run on different Nodes simultaneously.

But on one Node, the job can only be executed one by one. That is to say, if we only have one Node available (no matter how many executors it has), the three builds will executed one by one.

How can I config the job in this way, to run simultaneously? Currently, we have a lot of this kinds of Job/Project.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you need to [enable concurrent builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153255/jenkins-running-instances-of-single-build-concurrently).

Also you can use ssh-agent plugin to connect via ssh everywhere from your slave.

Comment: thanks for your response, Anotoly.
If I enable concurrent builds, two builds might be executed on same Node (with multiple executor) simultaneously. that is not what I want. 
one of requirements is: two builds cannot be executed simultaneously on same node

Comment: @RenboJiang you can use parametrized builds to pass necessary node for this purpose.