# Build is already in progress (ETA:N/A))?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, gerrit-trigger

I am working on Jenkins pipleline (Jenkins Version 2.138).. I pushed a change to gerrit and JobA triggered and started building on slave1 now, when I push another patchset, it says `Build is already in progress (ETA:N/A))`

Any inputs, why the build is in queue when the slaves are available to accept.?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153255/jenkins-running-instances-of-single-build-concurrently Is this what you need?

Comment: Thanks @K.B.That worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @K.B for the hint.. That solution worked for me. There are two ways to fix this issue

1. Add `concurrent: true` in JJB template that uncheck the **Do not allow concurrent builds** option on Jenkins UI
2. otherway is: *Uncheck* the **Do not allow concurrent builds** from Jenkins UI.