# Unable to run multiple instances of the same Jenkins job using cron

Tags: jenkins, parallel-processing, cron, scheduler, job-scheduling

I have a plain Jenkins job.

The job is restricted to run on a single node using label.

The node and the job settings are set to execute in parallel.

I use "[parameterized scheduler](https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=84705380#content/view/84705380)" plugin to run 4 instances of this job in parallel every 30 minutes like shown below:

```
*/30 * * * * %app=myapp1
*/30 * * * * %app=myapp2
*/30 * * * * %app=myapp3
*/30 * * * * %app=myapp4
```

As you can see the parameter(app=) is different for each run.

However, only one instance of this job runs tree first one i.e app=myapp1

Can you please suggest what needs to be done to fix the problem.

Note: when i change the cron time to */30, */31, */32, */33 then this works fine. Infact i even see parallel execution of the same job incase the job takes more than a minute to complete.

In summary my issue is about running multiple instances of the same job in parallel using cron and not a manual trigger.

With manual trigger i m able to have multiple instances running in parallel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins - Running instances of single build concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153255/jenkins-running-instances-of-single-build-concurrently)

Comment: Sorry my issue is different than the link you posted. My issue is about running multiple instances of the same job in parallel using cron. Your link does not talk about the cron issue. Running on parallel already works for me when triggered manually. The issue is when it gets triggered using the cron